# Bash scripting: How to tell if a partition can be mounted?

Tags: bash, filesystems, mount, python, automounting

Situation: Writing automated file mounting using Python on Linux. No Pythonic way that I can find to do it so using system calls (which technically means I am doing bash scripting, just that I am doing it through Python).

Problem: Getting disk labels are not sufficient for mounting the disks. For example, I am able to get the disk label `/dev/sda`, but only `/dev/sda1`  is mountable, `/dev/sda2` being a SWAP partition.

`fdisk` outputs and `parted` outputs are not really helping in helping me decide which disks can be mounted (i.e. have a valid readable filesystem)

Question: How can I, by using Linux/Bash commands, find out which disks can be mounted (I don't mind chaining more than 10 `grep` pipes to get my final result).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `lsblk` and `blkid` can be used to find out what's in a partition (e.g. swap, known filesystem, raw data).   They both have various options to specify the output format so you can extract just the info you need (e.g. filesystem type, fs label, uuid, etc).

IMO `blkid` is a better tool for scripted operations and, in my experience, is better at detecting what an existing partition is being used for, no matter what kind of block device is being examined (e.g. `lsblk` doesn't know what to do with a ZFS zvol. `blkid` treats it just like any other block device - which is exactly what it should do because that's exactly what a ZVOL is).  `lsblk` can be used in scripts, but is, IMO, oriented more towards interactive use with pretty-printed output.

e.g. on one of my systems:

```
# blkid /dev/sda*
/dev/sda: PTUUID="3a1e16ae" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: UUID="08799b67-8ed7-4cee-aea1-0f9e7bd1fc04" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3a1e16ae-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="db8bda5f-4f18-4abb-a151-08494e398047" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="3a1e16ae-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="fc967791-b9cf-4145-9047-8a8b223ac4bb" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="3a1e16ae-03"
```

Or if I want just the filesystem type of /dev/sda1:

```
# blkid -o value --match-tag TYPE /dev/sda1
ext4
```

See the man page for `blkid` for details.

BTW, `file -s` can also be used but the output is harder to parse.  e.g.

```
# file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=08799b67-8ed7-4cee-aea1-0f9e7bd1fc04 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```